# Removing data before the last forward slash in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a file location in a variable and all I need to do is get the value from the last `/` onwards.

For example the contents of my variable (named `myfile`) would look like `/home/tony/files/test.pdf` or `/tmp/admin.doc`.  I just want to go to the end of the variable and go backwards until I get to a `/` and then take the value from that point onwards.

Any ideas?

Comment: `lastIndexOf('/')` is your friend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`String.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```
var index = myfile.lastIndexOf('/');
if(index != -1)
{
    var newStr = myfile.substring(index + 1);
}
```

Another method of doing this would be to use regular expressions:

```
var newStr = myfile.replace(/^.*\/(?=[^\/]*$)/, '');
```

Comment: Wow thank you soo much for your quick reply and the answer.  You made it look so easy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var location = "/home/time/json.pdf";
var parts = location.split('/');
var index = parts.length-1;
alert(parts[index]);
```

this would do it, but with regex or substring I guess you could do this much faster.

Answer (score 0):

if you write it like this, a file name without any directory path will be returned unchanged.

```
myfile.substring(myfile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

with Regex

```js
var filePath = '/home/tony/files/test.pdf';
var fileName = filePath.match(/[^\/]*$/);

document.write(fileName);
```

without Regex

```js
var filePath = '/home/tony/files/test.pdf';
var fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();

document.write(fileName);
```