# Javascript regex to extract the string before the last backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

I am dealing with timezone's in Javascript and I need a regex that will extract everything, but the timezone name from it. For example, I have the timezone `America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires`. I want to extract the `America/Argentina` part with a regex. Currently I have this regex: `tz.match(/.*?(?=\/|$)/i)[0]` which extracts everything to the first backslash which works for most timezones (`America/Los_Angeles`), but not for all of them. How could I edit that regex so that it gets the string before the last value?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9380132

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'd personally suggest avoiding regular expressions for something like this, when simple string functions/methods would suffice admirably:

```
var stringVariable = 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires',
    text = stringVariable.substring(0, stringVariable.lastIndexOf('/'));
```